# subprocess.call requiring all parameters to be separated by commas

Tags: python

I used to be able to do a `subprocess.call(["command","-option value -option value"])`  and it would work  there was a change to the command to work properly with things in quotes, but now I have to change my subprocess call command to look like this:

```
subprocess.call(["command","-option","value","-option","value"])
```

is there something I can do to get it to work the other way again in python?

the `os.system("command -option value -option value")`  works the same as it did before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify `shell=True` to get subprocess.call to interpret the string.

See the note in the [subprocess.Popen constructor documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (the subprocess.call method takes the same arguments as the subprocess.Popen constructor).

Comment: OK, so I did this:
subprocess.call("command "+"-option value -option value", shell=True) and it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 45):

Avoid `shell=True` if you can -- it's a [security risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shelltrue-in-subprocess). For this purpose,  [shlex.split](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) suffices:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
subprocess.call(shlex.split("command -option value -option value"))
```

Comment: is this one better than the one above?  is there a benefit to using shelex?

Comment: `shlex.split` creates a list for you, basically. So it is pretty much equivalent to `subprocess.call(["command","-option","value","-option","value"])` without having to explicitly writing the list literal.

Comment: @Dag: it allows you to avoid using `shell=True`, which is a security risk.

Comment: why not just use "command -option value -option value".split(" ")

Comment: @Tom: `shlex.split` has a better chance of properly splitting a command-line string than `str.split`. For example, `shlex.split("command 'filename with spaces'")` correctly returns `['command', 'filename with spaces']` whereas `"command 'filename with spaces'".split()` incorrectly returns `['command', "'filename", 'with', "spaces'"]`.

Comment: @Tom: There are cases where `shlex.split` screws up, however. Such as `shlex.split("""file with \"quotes \'n spaces """)` (which  raises a `ValueError`) or `shlex.split(r'C:\Foo')` (the backslash is dropped). So it is sometimes better to manually craft the command/argument list yourself (without `shlex.split` or `str.split`).